# Booting behaves differently (and not always reproducible) with external disk plugged in via USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios, external-hard-drive

My machine used as a home server behaves differently when booted with an external drive plugged in over USB (tested with an exfat of ext4 partition on it).

Everything works just fine without having plugged in an external HDD over USB. With this external storage device plugged in, it did not work at all until I disabled "Legacy USB storage detect" in my BIOS. Funnily, the booting process now only sometimes does not work. The faulty behavior can't be reproduced by me. It is hard to find out, where the problem might be,

When the booting does not succeed, I end up in a Busybox Debian environment, which I did not even know of its existence on the machine before. The only OS I installed on the computer is a Debian 9. I have to unplug the USB device and have to switch off and on the computer's electricity to get my system back running then.

I set up in BIOS to boot from another local disk. Of course this local disk is set up to be the first place to check for booting. Like written avove, I also disabled "Legacy USB storage detect" in my BIOS. My BIOS firmware is the newest and got updated manually a year ago. [I have an old GIGABYTE motherboard with an updated BIOS (downloaded as mb_bios_ga-ma790gpt-ud3h_f4j.exe).]

Did I miss something and should better look for another solution other then in BIOS? How come, that the booting process sometimes works with the USB drive plugged in, but most of the times not? should not booting up my system always behave the same? Or does my computer potentially remember something from the last running state, that could change the next booting process? Where can I start to find out where my problem lies?

Comment: Apparently, my specific questions will not find answers here. So I will post, what I have done in the end - it might help somebody with this or a similar problem:

Comment: I downgraded the BIOS for the GIGABYTE Motherboard: GA-MA790GPT-UD3H to Version F3. I did not change anything in the BIOS settings. With that I got a message that the DMI will be updated in the first boot after the change. The message ended by stating "SUCCESS" after a while and the boot continued. This message comes every time, the system boots without the waiting, updating and the "SUCCESS" stating. With that it seems to work. When I plugged in an external hard drive, the system booted the last times without failures.